# Why is there difference between the "ideal scenario" and the "ideal simulation" for this isolation transformer model?

Tags: transformer, passive-networks

The illustration below shows how an isolation transformer is protecting from electrocution by not letting the current to loop through the earth at the secondary side. Neglecting the parasitic capacitances and assuming ideal conditions the current induced at secondary will loop as shown in red and not through the human(I believe "ideally" without any parasitics there will be no current passing through the human):

[image]

When I tried to simulate this again with ideal conditions where there is no parasitic capacitance ect, I observe the line voltage at one of the secondary terminals as shown below:

[image]

Then I first connected 1k Rhuman to bottom terminal and there is a tiny current passing through the Rhuman:

[image]

Later I connected 1k Rhuman to the upper terminal and there is a no current passing through the Rhuman:

[image]

My question is why I am observing voltage and tiny current between the secondary terminal and the earth in my simulation even though there are no parasitic capacitances?

Comment: Vary Rhuman up in value until you get 50% of the line-in voltage - you might find that Rhuman is 10 Mohm or 100 Mohm depending what the default Gmin is in your simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Because even a simulator needs a bit of reality built in.

You cannot have isolated nodes in a general simulator, as this introduces singularities in the differential equations. So, to avoid this there are additional simulator parameters that let some measure of reality “creep in” into the simulation.

In this particular case, it might be “gmin” the minimum conductance between any node and ground. Reduce it, and you will reduce the effect. Reduce it too much, and watch the simulator go singular.